# Hacer una peticion GET con fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

hola reciente estoy aprendiendo a usar fetch encontré en internet una api la cual me ofrece un servicio de random user ahora he estado intentando hacer una petición sencilla donde solo me devuelva un JSON q contenga usuarios mujeres, y de un país en especifico como por ejemplo "US" segun la documentancion de la misma api puedo hacer lo siguiente https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&nat=gb pero cuando estaba investigando sobre fetch encontre que puedo hacer peticiones pasando lo que quiero obtener a través  de un request por ejemplo

```
var miInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: misCabeceras,
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };
```

pasar miInit como segundo parametro en fetch. Ahora cuando intento hacer lo mismo pero con la api no resulta ya q me devuelve usuarios de genero masculino y de otras nacionalidades me podrian explicar que estoy haciendo mal? abajo les dejo mi codigo

```
async function request(){

    let dataRequest = {
       method: 'GET', 
       headers: {gender: "female", nat:"US"}
    }
    let response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api", dataRequest);
      console.log(response)
    let result = await response.json();
      console.log(result)
}

request()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las cabeceras y los parámetros son cosas totalmente diferentes, quizá esto sea más aproximado a lo que buscas y que es lo recomendado por el fetch standard

```
async function request(){
    let url = new URL("https://randomuser.me/api");
    const params = {gender: "female", nat:"US"};
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));
    const dataRequest = {
       method: 'GET'
    };
    let response = await fetch(url, dataRequest);
      console.log(response)
    let result = await response.json();
      console.log(result)
}
```

Más información
    https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api

Comment: gracias :D eso es lo q queria saber, entoncs que puedo enviar por cabecera? o q deberia enviar?

Comment: en las cabeceras van las cabeceras standard de http
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Cabeceras_HTTP

Answer (score 2):

No te regresa el resultado que esperas porque estás pasando los parámetros como cabeceras.

Intenta reemplazando:

```
let response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api", dataRequest);
```

Por:

```
let response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&nat=gb", dataRequest);
```

Comment: es la unica forma de hacerlo? es decir es lo que justamente queria evitar pasarlo por la url de esta manera "https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&nat=gb"

Comment: Eso depende del API, si no acepta que le pases los filtros como cabeceras, no puedes hacer nada. ¿Porque quieres pasarlos como cabeceras?